# How are new Stack Exchange sites opened?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, site-proposal

I don't know how new Stack Exchange sites get opened. I've found some of the new SE sites to be very useless. There are many different and important subjects that are not being addressed by any SE site. I strongly suggest creating a new SE site about unscientific psychology. I have come across many questions that are related to human problems that I would like to ask on an SE site.

How do new SE sites get opened up? Is there a place for voting up new SE sites?

Comment: [Psychology and Psychiatry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14303/psychology-and-psychiatry?referrer=yO19QOmEeucN5QfMOt5KEg2)

Comment: @Downvoter - Honestly Psychology and Psychiatry category is so scientic against what i wanted.I am looking others

Comment: @Freshblood, you want a non-scientific psychology SE?

Comment: @Freshblood, by "there are many different and important subjects" do you mean subjects that SE sites aren't addressing, or topics that SE sites are addressing poorly? And by "found many question" do you mean that you personally have questions, or that you've seen lots of questions around that could benefit from being asked on an SE?

Comment: @Popular Demand, yes none-scientific psychology means questions are related human problems, not about psychology science subjects.

Comment: @Popular Demand - Yes,"there are many different and important subjects" do you mean subjects that SE sites aren't addressing. I mean "you've seen lots of questions around that could benefit from being asked on an SE"

Comment: By "very useless", I hope you mean useless to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can read about the actual process here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq